# Sharing guest VPN connection with host computer using Hyper-V

Tags: vpn, hyper-v, bridge

My company's VPN client doesn't work with Windows 10 latest Insider Builds (HOST), so I thought of using a virtual machine (Windows 10 RTM GUEST) with the VPN client installed.

Is it possible to make the host PC to use the VPN connection that resides in the guest? (using Hyper-V)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible for host to use VPN Connection from inside the guest

But the opposite it possible

So if your Host was on a supported OS that you company supported for VPN and then you used Windows 10 inside, then you could share VPN from Host to Guest not the other way around

I personally use Mac as my Host and i have a Windows 10 and i share my VPN from Mac(host) to my Window(guest)